# How Could Adjust Vertical Spacing Between Cards

Tags: html, css

Here is my html & css code 
I've been trying for last two days to adjust the vertical spacing between cards

How could I fix the vertical space between cards 
I havetryed `margin-bottom: 0` all other solutions from stackoverflow but noting helpful

**UPDATE :**

I'm trying to make the space inside orange box as well as space inside green box , I spent two days only for this issue : [Check This Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YATW.png)

[jsfiddle.com](http://jsfiddle.net/e6raLLc5/117/)

Comment: Please don't post a link to your code but post your code directly. Also please note: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 1):

Even if margin bottom is applied as zero, the height of the images causing this issue because each card has different size of images. Due to that, the cards are adjusting with the longest card and taking the margin. Therefore have a fixed height for the image.

```css
.mp-image {
  height: 10rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cssauthor.com/wp-content/plugins/core-extend/assets/css/core-extend.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cssauthor.com/wp-content/themes/bitz/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cssauthor.com/wp-content/themes/bitz-child/style.css">
</head>


<div id="main" class="clearfix">
  <div id="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" id="content">
      <div class="mnky-posts clearfix mp-layout-1 column-count-4">

        <div class="wrapper">


          <div id="post-141427" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" class="mp-container clearfix">
            <a href="https://cssauthor.com/deals/mockuuups-studio-30-offer/" class="mp-image" rel="bookmark">
              <div itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject"><img src="http://media.idownloadblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/iPhone-X-Wallpaper-by-Remy_Loz-iDownloadBlog-5.png" alt="Mockuuups Studio Offer" height="175px" width="300px">
                <meta itemprop="url" content="https://cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Mockuuups-Studio-Offer.jpg">
                <meta itemprop="width" content="600">
                <meta itemprop="height" content="350">
              </div>
            </a>
            <div class="mp-content">
              <span class="mp-category"><a href="https://cssauthor.com/offers/">Deals</a></span>
              <h2 itemprop="headline" class="mp-title"><a itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" href="https://cssauthor.com/deals/mockuuups-studio-30-offer/" title="View Mockuuups Studio | 30 % Offer" rel="bookmark">Mockuuups Studio | 30 % Offer</a>
              </h2><span class="mp-deal-date">Expired!</span><span class="mp-views"><span
                                class="views-low" title="Views"><i class="post-icon icon-views"></i> 1262<meta
                                itemprop="interactionCount" content="UserPageVisits:1262"></span></span>
            </div>
            <time datetime="2017-01-31T11:59:35+00:00" itemprop="datePublished"></time>
            <time class="meta-date-modified" datetime="2017-05-12T11:28:00+00:00" itemprop="dateModified"></time>
            <div class="hidden-meta" itemprop="publisher" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
              <div class="hidden-meta" itemprop="logo" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
                <meta itemprop="url" content="https://www.cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/CSS-Author-New-LOGO.svg">
                <meta itemprop="width" content="">
                <meta itemprop="height" content="">
              </div>
              <meta itemprop="name" content="CSS Author">
            </div>
          </div>


          <div id="post-141427" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" class="mp-container clearfix">
            <a href="https://cssauthor.com/deals/mockuuups-studio-30-offer/" class="mp-image" rel="bookmark">
              <div itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject"><img src="https://images.template.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Portfolio-Website-Template-with-Grid-Based-Layout.jpg" alt="Mockuuups Studio Offer" height="175" width="300">
                <meta itemprop="url" content="https://cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Mockuuups-Studio-Offer.jpg">
                <meta itemprop="width" content="600">
                <meta itemprop="height" content="350">
              </div>
            </a>
            <div class="mp-content">
              <span class="mp-category"><a href="https://cssauthor.com/offers/">Deals</a></span>
              <h2 itemprop="headline" class="mp-title"><a itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" href="https://cssauthor.com/deals/mockuuups-studio-30-offer/" title="View Mockuuups Studio | 30 % Offer" rel="bookmark">Mockuuups Studio | 30 % Offer</a>
              </h2><span class="mp-deal-date">Expired!</span><span class="mp-views"><span
                                class="views-low" title="Views"><i class="post-icon icon-views"></i> 1262<meta
                                itemprop="interactionCount" content="UserPageVisits:1262"></span></span>
            </div>
            <time datetime="2017-01-31T11:59:35+00:00" itemprop="datePublished"></time>
            <time class="meta-date-modified" datetime="2017-05-12T11:28:00+00:00" itemprop="dateModified"></time>
            <div class="hidden-meta" itemprop="publisher" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
              <div class="hidden-meta" itemprop="logo" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
                <meta itemprop="url" content="https://www.cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/CSS-Author-New-LOGO.svg">
                <meta itemprop="width" content="">
                <meta itemprop="height" content="">
              </div>
              <meta itemprop="name" content="CSS Author">
            </div>
          </div>


          <div id="post-141427" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" class="mp-container clearfix">
            <a href="https://cssauthor.com/deals/mockuuups-studio-30-offer/" class="mp-image" rel="bookmark">
              <div itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject"><img src="https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/media/2016-07-22-how-to-extend-django-user-model/featured-post-image.jpg" alt="Mockuuups Studio Offer" height="175" width="300">
                <meta itemprop="url" content="https://cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Mockuuups-Studio-Offer.jpg">
                <meta itemprop="width" content="600">
                <meta itemprop="height" content="350">
              </div>
            </a>
            <div class="mp-content">
              <span class="mp-category"><a href="https://cssauthor.com/offers/">Deals</a></span>
              <h2 itemprop="headline" class="mp-title"><a itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" href="https://cssauthor.com/deals/mockuuups-studio-30-offer/" title="View Mockuuups Studio | 30 % Offer" rel="bookmark">Mockuuups Studio | 30 % Offer</a>
              </h2><span class="mp-deal-date">Expired!</span><span class="mp-views"><span
                                class="views-low" title="Views"><i class="post-icon icon-views"></i> 1262<meta
                                itemprop="interactionCount" content="UserPageVisits:1262"></span></span>
            </div>
            <time datetime="2017-01-31T11:59:35+00:00" itemprop="datePublished"></time>
            <time class="meta-date-modified" datetime="2017-05-12T11:28:00+00:00" itemprop="dateModified"></time>
            <div class="hidden-meta" itemprop="publisher" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
              <div class="hidden-meta" itemprop="logo" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
                <meta itemprop="url" content="https://www.cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/CSS-Author-New-LOGO.svg">
                <meta itemprop="width" content="">
                <meta itemprop="height" content="">
              </div>
              <meta itemprop="name" content="CSS Author">
            </div>
          </div>


          <div id="post-141427" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" class="mp-container clearfix">
            <a href="https://cssauthor.com/deals/mockuuups-studio-30-offer/" class="mp-image" rel="bookmark">
              <div itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a86f644e962bc2b983b2e5551138212d?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="Mockuuups Studio Offer" height="175" width="300">
                <meta itemprop="url" content="https://cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Mockuuups-Studio-Offer.jpg">
                <meta itemprop="width" content="600">
                <meta itemprop="height" content="350">
              </div>
            </a>
            <div class="mp-content">
              <span class="mp-category"><a href="https://cssauthor.com/offers/">Deals</a></span>
              <h2 itemprop="headline" class="mp-title"><a itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" href="https://cssauthor.com/deals/mockuuups-studio-30-offer/" title="View Mockuuups Studio | 30 % Offer" rel="bookmark">Mockuuups Studio | 30 % Offer</a>
              </h2><span class="mp-deal-date">Expired!</span><span class="mp-views"><span
                                class="views-low" title="Views"><i class="post-icon icon-views"></i> 1262<meta
                                itemprop="interactionCount" content="UserPageVisits:1262"></span></span>
            </div>
            <time datetime="2017-01-31T11:59:35+00:00" itemprop="datePublished"></time>
            <time class="meta-date-modified" datetime="2017-05-12T11:28:00+00:00" itemprop="dateModified"></time>
            <div class="hidden-meta" itemprop="publisher" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
              <div class="hidden-meta" itemprop="logo" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
                <meta itemprop="url" content="https://www.cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/CSS-Author-New-LOGO.svg">
                <meta itemprop="width" content="">
                <meta itemprop="height" content="">
              </div>
              <meta itemprop="name" content="CSS Author">
            </div>
          </div>





          <div id="post-141427" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" class="mp-container clearfix">
            <a href="https://cssauthor.com/deals/mockuuups-studio-30-offer/" class="mp-image" rel="bookmark">
              <div itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject"><img src="https://images.template.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Portfolio-Website-Template-with-Grid-Based-Layout.jpg" alt="Mockuuups Studio Offer" height="175" width="300">
                <meta itemprop="url" content="https://cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Mockuuups-Studio-Offer.jpg">
                <meta itemprop="width" content="600">
                <meta itemprop="height" content="350">
              </div>
            </a>
            <div class="mp-content">
              <span class="mp-category"><a href="https://cssauthor.com/offers/">Deals</a></span>
              <h2 itemprop="headline" class="mp-title"><a itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" href="https://cssauthor.com/deals/mockuuups-studio-30-offer/" title="View Mockuuups Studio | 30 % Offer" rel="bookmark">Mockuuups Studio | 30 % Offer</a>
              </h2><span class="mp-deal-date">Expired!</span><span class="mp-views"><span
                                class="views-low" title="Views"><i class="post-icon icon-views"></i> 1262<meta
                                itemprop="interactionCount" content="UserPageVisits:1262"></span></span>
            </div>
            <time datetime="2017-01-31T11:59:35+00:00" itemprop="datePublished"></time>
            <time class="meta-date-modified" datetime="2017-05-12T11:28:00+00:00" itemprop="dateModified"></time>
            <div class="hidden-meta" itemprop="publisher" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
              <div class="hidden-meta" itemprop="logo" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
                <meta itemprop="url" content="https://www.cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/CSS-Author-New-LOGO.svg">
                <meta itemprop="width" content="">
                <meta itemprop="height" content="">
              </div>
              <meta itemprop="name" content="CSS Author">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="post-141427" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" class="mp-container clearfix">
            <a href="https://cssauthor.com/deals/mockuuups-studio-30-offer/" class="mp-image" rel="bookmark">
              <div itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject"><img src="https://cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Awesome-HTML5-and-CSS3-Website-Design-Inspiration-600x350.jpg" alt="Mockuuups Studio Offer" height="175" width="300">
                <meta itemprop="url" content="https://cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Mockuuups-Studio-Offer.jpg">
                <meta itemprop="width" content="600">
                <meta itemprop="height" content="350">
              </div>
            </a>
            <div class="mp-content">
              <span class="mp-category"><a href="https://cssauthor.com/offers/">Deals</a></span>
              <h2 itemprop="headline" class="mp-title"><a itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" href="https://cssauthor.com/deals/mockuuups-studio-30-offer/" title="View Mockuuups Studio | 30 % Offer" rel="bookmark">Mockuuups Studio | 30 % Offer</a>
              </h2><span class="mp-deal-date">Expired!</span><span class="mp-views"><span
                                class="views-low" title="Views"><i class="post-icon icon-views"></i> 1262<meta
                                itemprop="interactionCount" content="UserPageVisits:1262"></span></span>
            </div>
            <time datetime="2017-01-31T11:59:35+00:00" itemprop="datePublished"></time>
            <time class="meta-date-modified" datetime="2017-05-12T11:28:00+00:00" itemprop="dateModified"></time>
            <div class="hidden-meta" itemprop="publisher" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
              <div class="hidden-meta" itemprop="logo" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
                <meta itemprop="url" content="https://www.cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/CSS-Author-New-LOGO.svg">
                <meta itemprop="width" content="">
                <meta itemprop="height" content="">
              </div>
              <meta itemprop="name" content="CSS Author">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="post-141427" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" class="mp-container clearfix">
            <a href="https://cssauthor.com/deals/mockuuups-studio-30-offer/" class="mp-image" rel="bookmark">
              <div itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject"><img src="https://images.template.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Website-Template-with-Grid-Based-for-Web-Designer.jpg" alt="Mockuuups Studio Offer" height="175" width="300">
                <meta itemprop="url" content="https://cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Mockuuups-Studio-Offer.jpg">
                <meta itemprop="width" content="600">
                <meta itemprop="height" content="350">
              </div>
            </a>
            <div class="mp-content">
              <span class="mp-category"><a href="https://cssauthor.com/offers/">Deals</a></span>
              <h2 itemprop="headline" class="mp-title"><a itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" href="https://cssauthor.com/deals/mockuuups-studio-30-offer/" title="View Mockuuups Studio | 30 % Offer" rel="bookmark">Mockuuups Studio | 30 % Offer</a>
              </h2><span class="mp-deal-date">Expired!</span><span class="mp-views"><span
                                class="views-low" title="Views"><i class="post-icon icon-views"></i> 1262<meta
                                itemprop="interactionCount" content="UserPageVisits:1262"></span></span>
            </div>
            <time datetime="2017-01-31T11:59:35+00:00" itemprop="datePublished"></time>
            <time class="meta-date-modified" datetime="2017-05-12T11:28:00+00:00" itemprop="dateModified"></time>
            <div class="hidden-meta" itemprop="publisher" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
              <div class="hidden-meta" itemprop="logo" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
                <meta itemprop="url" content="https://www.cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/CSS-Author-New-LOGO.svg">
                <meta itemprop="width" content="">
                <meta itemprop="height" content="">
              </div>
              <meta itemprop="name" content="CSS Author">
            </div>
          </div>











          <div id="post-141427" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" class="mp-container clearfix">
            <a href="https://cssauthor.com/deals/mockuuups-studio-30-offer/" class="mp-image" rel="bookmark">
              <div itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject"><img src="./Exclusive Deals for Designers and Developers » CSS Author_files/Mockuuups-Studio-Offer-600x350.jpg" alt="Mockuuups Studio Offer" height="175" width="300">
                <meta itemprop="url" content="https://cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Mockuuups-Studio-Offer.jpg">
                <meta itemprop="width" content="600">
                <meta itemprop="height" content="350">
              </div>
            </a>
            <div class="mp-content">
              <span class="mp-category"><a href="https://cssauthor.com/offers/">Deals</a></span>
              <h2 itemprop="headline" class="mp-title"><a itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" href="https://cssauthor.com/deals/mockuuups-studio-30-offer/" title="View Mockuuups Studio | 30 % Offer" rel="bookmark">Mockuuups Studio | 30 % Offer</a>
              </h2><span class="mp-deal-date">Expired!</span><span class="mp-views"><span
                                class="views-low" title="Views"><i class="post-icon icon-views"></i> 1262<meta
                                itemprop="interactionCount" content="UserPageVisits:1262"></span></span>
            </div>
            <time datetime="2017-01-31T11:59:35+00:00" itemprop="datePublished"></time>
            <time class="meta-date-modified" datetime="2017-05-12T11:28:00+00:00" itemprop="dateModified"></time>
            <div class="hidden-meta" itemprop="publisher" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
              <div class="hidden-meta" itemprop="logo" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
                <meta itemprop="url" content="https://www.cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/CSS-Author-New-LOGO.svg">
                <meta itemprop="width" content="">
                <meta itemprop="height" content="">
              </div>
              <meta itemprop="name" content="CSS Author">
            </div>
          </div>


          <div id="post-141427" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" class="mp-container clearfix">
            <a href="https://cssauthor.com/deals/mockuuups-studio-30-offer/" class="mp-image" rel="bookmark">
              <div itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject"><img src="https://cdn.colorlib.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/Floating_Sign_Up_Login_Form.png" alt="Mockuuups Studio Offer" height="175" width="300">
                <meta itemprop="url" content="https://cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Mockuuups-Studio-Offer.jpg">
                <meta itemprop="width" content="600">
                <meta itemprop="height" content="350">
              </div>
            </a>
            <div class="mp-content">
              <span class="mp-category"><a href="https://cssauthor.com/offers/">Deals</a></span>
              <h2 itemprop="headline" class="mp-title"><a itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" href="https://cssauthor.com/deals/mockuuups-studio-30-offer/" title="View Mockuuups Studio | 30 % Offer" rel="bookmark">Mockuuups Studio | 30 % Offer</a>
              </h2><span class="mp-deal-date">Expired!</span><span class="mp-views"><span
                                class="views-low" title="Views"><i class="post-icon icon-views"></i> 1262<meta
                                itemprop="interactionCount" content="UserPageVisits:1262"></span></span>
            </div>
            <time datetime="2017-01-31T11:59:35+00:00" itemprop="datePublished"></time>
            <time class="meta-date-modified" datetime="2017-05-12T11:28:00+00:00" itemprop="dateModified"></time>
            <div class="hidden-meta" itemprop="publisher" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
              <div class="hidden-meta" itemprop="logo" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
                <meta itemprop="url" content="https://www.cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/CSS-Author-New-LOGO.svg">
                <meta itemprop="width" content="">
                <meta itemprop="height" content="">
              </div>
              <meta itemprop="name" content="CSS Author">
            </div>
          </div>


          <div id="post-141427" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" class="mp-container clearfix">
            <a href="https://cssauthor.com/deals/mockuuups-studio-30-offer/" class="mp-image" rel="bookmark">
              <div itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject"><img src="https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/media/2016-07-22-how-to-extend-django-user-model/featured-post-image.jpg" alt="Mockuuups Studio Offer" height="175" width="300">
                <meta itemprop="url" content="https://cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Mockuuups-Studio-Offer.jpg">
                <meta itemprop="width" content="600">
                <meta itemprop="height" content="350">
              </div>
            </a>
            <div class="mp-content">
              <span class="mp-category"><a href="https://cssauthor.com/offers/">Deals</a></span>
              <h2 itemprop="headline" class="mp-title"><a itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" href="https://cssauthor.com/deals/mockuuups-studio-30-offer/" title="View Mockuuups Studio | 30 % Offer" rel="bookmark">Mockuuups Studio | 30 % Offer</a>
              </h2><span class="mp-deal-date">Expired!</span><span class="mp-views"><span
                                class="views-low" title="Views"><i class="post-icon icon-views"></i> 1262<meta
                                itemprop="interactionCount" content="UserPageVisits:1262"></span></span>
            </div>
            <time datetime="2017-01-31T11:59:35+00:00" itemprop="datePublished"></time>
            <time class="meta-date-modified" datetime="2017-05-12T11:28:00+00:00" itemprop="dateModified"></time>
            <div class="hidden-meta" itemprop="publisher" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
              <div class="hidden-meta" itemprop="logo" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
                <meta itemprop="url" content="https://www.cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/CSS-Author-New-LOGO.svg">
                <meta itemprop="width" content="">
                <meta itemprop="height" content="">
              </div>
              <meta itemprop="name" content="CSS Author">
            </div>
          </div>


          <div id="post-141427" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" class="mp-container clearfix">
            <a href="https://cssauthor.com/deals/mockuuups-studio-30-offer/" class="mp-image" rel="bookmark">
              <div itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject"><img src="https://images.template.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Website-Template-with-Grid-Based-for-Web-Designer.jpg" alt="Mockuuups Studio Offer" height="175" width="300">
                <meta itemprop="url" content="https://cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Mockuuups-Studio-Offer.jpg">
                <meta itemprop="width" content="600">
                <meta itemprop="height" content="350">
              </div>
            </a>
            <div class="mp-content">
              <span class="mp-category"><a href="https://cssauthor.com/offers/">Deals</a></span>
              <h2 itemprop="headline" class="mp-title"><a itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" href="https://cssauthor.com/deals/mockuuups-studio-30-offer/" title="View Mockuuups Studio | 30 % Offer" rel="bookmark">Mockuuups Studio | 30 % Offer</a>
              </h2><span class="mp-deal-date">Expired!</span><span class="mp-views"><span
                                class="views-low" title="Views"><i class="post-icon icon-views"></i> 1262<meta
                                itemprop="interactionCount" content="UserPageVisits:1262"></span></span>
            </div>
            <time datetime="2017-01-31T11:59:35+00:00" itemprop="datePublished"></time>
            <time class="meta-date-modified" datetime="2017-05-12T11:28:00+00:00" itemprop="dateModified"></time>
            <div class="hidden-meta" itemprop="publisher" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
              <div class="hidden-meta" itemprop="logo" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
                <meta itemprop="url" content="https://www.cssauthor.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/CSS-Author-New-LOGO.svg">
                <meta itemprop="width" content="">
                <meta itemprop="height" content="">
              </div>
              <meta itemprop="name" content="CSS Author">
            </div>
          </div>





        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="pagination">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

UPDATE: 
Add `overflow:hidden` if the image height is more than card height.

Comment: This didn't work and opposite of what i'm looking for !

Comment: @Mesh you want to reduce the vertical margin is it? Try now. Your suggested solution is working though. Margin-bottom 0 is adjusted according to the longest card. If all cards are in same vertical length, it will solve

Comment: @Mesh this is because of the different size of images. I have updated the question. You can define the height of the mp-image as you wish

Comment: plus In desktop version image over height the it's div

Comment: I have updated the answer again. Please refresh and check

Comment: Check this and resize the one , see first card image height : http://jsfiddle.net/e6raLLc5/122/

Comment: add an overflow:hidden to the same place. Check the updated answer css @Mesh

Comment: if the solution worked, please put a tick to the answer as well. Cheers :) @Mesh

Comment: Yes it's much better now, I'll keep this code for my second solution if I didn't find what i'm looking for by end of today, thx so much

Comment: @Mesh please do accept the answer since it is the solution